# Buttons not rendering in Gridview while binding Grid using JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am binding the Gridview using WebMethod (JQuery), I have button inside Template field but it is not getting rendered at runtime. Button does get rendered when I bind the grid from aspx.cs code. I have tried with both HTML button and ASP.Net Button. My code is as below.

```js
var maxRecords = 10;
var requestCount = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#btnLoad').click(loadData);
});

function loadData() {
 // Since first set was fetched by server code.
 requestCount = requestCount + 1;

 var startRecord = requestCount * maxRecords;

 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "AuthorList.aspx/GetAuthors",
  data: "{ \"startRecord\":" + startRecord + ", \"maxRecords\":" + maxRecords + " }",
  beforeSend: function () {
      $('#divLoad').html('<img src="loading.gif" width="364" height="276" />');
  },
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: bindGrid
 });
}

function bindGrid(data) {
 // Get list of authors from response.
 var dataRows = data.d;
 $('#divLoad').html('');
 if (dataRows.length == 0) {
  alert('no more data to load');
  return;
 }

 for (var i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {

  $('#gvAuthors').append('<tr>' + '<td>' + dataRows[i].ID + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + dataRows[i].Fname + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + dataRows[i].LName+ '</td>' +
        '<td>' + dataRows[i].Address + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + dataRows[i].Major + '</td>' +
     '</tr>');
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<asp:GridView ID="gvAuthors" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FName" HeaderText="FName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LName" HeaderText="LName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Major" HeaderText="Major" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Please help...